# How to show that Gauss-Seidel iterative method is equivalent to successively setting each component of residual vector to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-analysis, iterative-method

As stated in the title, it's said in the book that Gauss-Seidel iterative method is equivalent to successively setting each component of residual vector to zero. After rearranging G-S scheme, I got the following relation regarding the update of residual:

$$
r^{(k+1)} = U(D-L)^{-1}r^{(k)},
$$

but I still can't see why this conclusion holds. Any help?

Comment: If $D,L,U$ mean what I think they mean, it should be $(D-L)^{-1}U$, not $U(D-L)^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh yes, for Ax=b, D, L and U are respectively the diagonal, lower triangular and upper triangular of A!

Comment: Can you reference the book you're mentioning?

Comment: @nicoguaro Oh yes, I am referring to chapter 2 of the 'A multigrid tutorial‘ book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given approximated solution $\mathbf x^{(k)}$, we define the residual vector $\mathbf r^{(k)} := \mathbf b - \mathbf A\,\mathbf x^{(k)} $. Now we want to update $x^{(k)}_i \rightarrow x^{(k+1)}_i$ in such a way so that the $i$th component of the new residual vanishes:
$$
r^{(k+1)}_i = b_i - \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\,x^{(k+1)}_j = 0, \\
b_i - \left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{ij}\,x^{(k+1)}_j + a_{ii}\,x^{(k+1)}_i + \sum_{j=i+1}^n a_{ij}\,x^{(k+1)}_j\right) = 0, \\
x^{(k+1)}_i = \frac{1}{a_{ii}} \left(b_i - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{ij}\,x^{(k+1)}_j - \sum_{j=i+1}^n a_{ij}\,x^{(k+1)}_j\right).
$$ 
Assuming that all the other components stay the same, we may rewrite this formula as
$$
x^{(k+1)}_i = \frac{1}{a_{ii}} \left(b_i - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{ij}\,x^{(k)}_j - \sum_{j=i+1}^n a_{ij}\,x^{(k)}_j\right).
$$
Now, if we introduce matrix notation $\mathbf A = \mathbf L + \mathbf D + \mathbf U$ with strictly lower, diagonal, and strictly upper parts of the original matrix, we may rewrite the last equation as
$$
\mathbf L\,\mathbf x^{(k)} + \mathbf D\,\mathbf x^{(k+1)} + \mathbf U\,\mathbf x^{(k)} = \mathbf b, \\
\mathbf x^{(k+1)} = -\mathbf D^{-1}\left(\mathbf L + \mathbf U\right)\mathbf x^{(k)} + \mathbf D^{-1}\,\mathbf b;
$$
this is well-known Jacobi method.

Note that at the $i$th step we have already updated components $1, 2, \dots, i-1$, so let’s use these updated values:
$$
x^{(k+1)}_i = \frac{1}{a_{ii}} \left(b_i - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{ij}\,x^{(k+1)}_j - \sum_{j=i+1}^n a_{ij}\,x^{(k)}_j\right),
$$
or
$$
\mathbf L\,\mathbf x^{(k+1)} + \mathbf D\,\mathbf x^{(k+1)} + \mathbf U\,\mathbf x^{(k)} = \mathbf b, \\
\mathbf x^{(k+1)} = -(\mathbf D + \mathbf L)^{-1}\,\mathbf U\,\mathbf x^{(k)} + (\mathbf D + \mathbf L)^{-1}\,\mathbf b.
$$
This is Gauss–Seidel method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think it's right. According to your argument, the Jacobi method would also set the i-th component of residual to zero, but it's not!

Comment: This *is* true. Jacobi annihilates $i$th component of the residual assuming all the other components of the soln vector stay unchanged; Gauss–Seidel does the same but uses $(k+1)$th step (already updated) components of the soln vector.